# Separated characters in right to left languages in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, unicode

I embedded 1 font and it's OK in Opera and IE, but in Firefox 10 the characters are separated.

The related code is here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "rlfont";
    src: url("rlfont.ttf");
}

body {
    font: 14px/1.7 "rlfont";
}

.main { /* for the section shown in screenshot */
direction: rtl; 
margin-top: 25px;
width: 550px;  
float: right;
text-align: right;
```

}

I also add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

and even this:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
```

in .htaccess, but it still not work.

I also played with View > Character encoding in Firefox, but still that did not work.

This shows the problem: 
[image: Problem]

And this is what it should be:
[image: Desired result]

Comment: Please add a Screenshot which shows us how it should look like. Maybe you could play with `letter-spacing`.

Comment: Have you tried to declare the `direction` property to the specific class

     `.technology {
         direction: rtl;
     }`

or to all of the body

    `body {
         direction: rtl;
     }`?

Comment: letter-spacing just get theme together and dont join theme

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Some Persian and Arabic fonts are not properly converted to WOFF, so they don't display properly in Firefox.  IE use EOT and Firefox use WOFF (not TTF or EOT).

I found a download link for this popular font which is properly converted:
http://mihandownload.com/2011/09/css3-font-face-methods-and-optimized-font-firefox6.php